# Precedence of function call in C++ and Python

Tags: python, c++, operator-precedence

I have two similar codes in C++ and Python.
**C++ Code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i = 0;

int fcn()
{
    i = 1;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    i = 0;
    i = i + fcn();
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

`Output: 2`

The output is 2, and I think it is because of the precedence of function call is higher than addition.

**Python code**

```
def fcn():
    global x
    x = 1
    return 1

x = 0
x = x + fcn()
print(x)
```

`Output: 1`

The output is 1, which I am not sure how it works.
This [page](https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Evalerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) says that function call also has higher priority than addition in Python. 
So, why does these two codes have different ouputs, is there any misunderstanding?

Comment: You never even call `fcn` in your C++ code...?

Comment: Your C++ code has [**undefined behavior**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior).

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/315052

Comment: @jxh That's C, and C++ has a delightful tradition of changing fundamental things once in a while.

Comment: Where do you call `fcn()` in the c++ code?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether OP is calling `fcn` or not. The code has UB.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my C++ code.

Comment: @AnoopRana The program has unspecified behavior, but not undefined behavior. It will output either `1` or `2`. (Oh just noticed that the code was edited! You were correct before)

Comment: Note that operator precedence isn't actually the same as the order of evaluation of operands. You are correct that function call has higher precedence than addition. `x + fcn()` is interpreted as `(x) + (fcn())`, not as `(x + fcn)()`. But given that the expression is interpreted as `(x) + (fcn())`, that still doesn't tell you whether `x` or `fcn()` is evaluated first.

Comment: @user17732522 Ok, lol

Comment: Btw. the question is not entirely clear on whether you are asking about the C++ code or the Python code (you should try to avoid asking two things in one). The linked duplicate explains the problem in case of C++, but as far as I am aware (might be wrong though) in Python there is a defined order of evaluation. So the explanation in the duplicate is not applicable to Python.

Comment: @AnoopRana Like https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116940/c-questions-and-answers or https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec? Though I have never been there.